# Communicating with gallant hawk familiar

Tags: dnd-4e

I recently bought a `Gallant Hawk` and I was wondering what I need in terms of feats, powers, etc. for communicating with it.

Also, what other rules are involved (what I need to know) when communicating?

I am a `Wood Elf Swordmage` if that helps with answering the question.

Comment: Could you give us some details as to how you acquired this hawk? Is it through game mechanics or is it something you encountered? Are you looking for a Rules as written answer or a house rule kind of thing?

Comment: Hey their, Pat Ludwig managed to answer the question for me :) However to answer your question as to how I acquired the hawk. Currently my group are venturing the forgotten realms although I cannot remember the towns name we ventured to but it was hosting a 3 day trading fair type thing (forget the word) and in it we were able to buy almost anything available to us from the compendium etc.. with exceptions but long story short I brought myself a young gallant hawk, but currently cannot communicate with it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [Gallant Hawk](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/companion.aspx?id=81) as a familiar (it's the only Gallant Hawk I see in the Compendium) then you are looking for the [Bonded Familiar](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=739) feat from Arcane Power.

> **Benefit**: You and your familiar can communicate telepathically out to a range of 10 squares. You must have line of sight and line of effect to your familiar to communicate with it in this manner.